# How to start a new instance of Windows Service using ServiceController in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, windows-services

I have a Windows Service Application which i have installed using Visual Studio Setup Installer.The Windows Service Application is using C# Socket Program to read data from server using Ip and Port number and write it into the text file continuously.The ip address and port number is read from the database.Now as per my requirement,Suppose the Client wants to add one more server ip address and port number in this case how can i create a new instance of the data capture application in windows service..
Here is my code in Windows Service OnStart() method..

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _thread = new Thread(DoWork);
        _thread.Start();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you dont need to restart the service..

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _thread1 = new Thread(DoWork);
    _thread1.Start();
    _thread2 = new Thread(DoWork);
    _thread2.Start();
}
```

Pass some parameters to both the threads and then work accordingly

Comment: Suppose the Windows Service application is started with only one ip and port number and later Client added one more Ip and port ..In this case how can _thread2 will be started as first thread will be running the DoWork() method .How can Onstart() will be called again to run _thraed2 ?

Comment: for that you will have use a timer in service which will check if another ip is added or not... if another ip is added then start a new thread

Comment: If i will restart the service once new Ip and port no. has been added ..will it do the needfull?will it will start both the threads at the same time?I want to restart the service using ServiceController in c#

Comment: yes it will do the same thing.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx this is the link for service controller read the example

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to create a second instance of service for that. just start another thread and pass it the second IP and port as parameter.

Comment: As the Socket program is continuously listening to the ip and port once it will start the  _thread = new Thread(DoWork); it will never come for the OnStart(string[] args) method of the windows Service.Do i need to restart the Windows Service application once new Ip and port number has been enetred?